# LWC - Cannot read property * of undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map

I'm trying to implement a Google map using LWC, the component is on the record page called Project__c, I want to use Address__c as an input:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ADDRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/PRoject__c.Address__c';


export default class Map extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ADDRESS_FIELD] })
    project;

    mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: {
                City: this.project.ADDRESS_FIELD.value,
                State: 'Norway',
            },
        },
    ];
    zoomLevel = 5;
}
```

When I open the record page I get the following error:

> render threw an error in 'c:map' [Cannot read property 'ADDRESS_FIELD'
>   of undefined]

The Project__c.Address__c is populated, so I'm not sure how to continue.

I tried replacing `this.project.ADDRESS_FIELD.value` with `this.project.ADDRESS_FIELD` but got the same results.

Comment: Do a `console.log` to `this.project` and see the structure it returns.

Comment: @Raul, when I add console.log('something'); I see the following error in VSC: 'unexpected token' - any thoughts ?

Comment: Logging `this.project` will result in `undefined` - just as the error says. You may have a typo in import section. Is your SObject's API Name `PRoject__c` or `Project__c`? Can you also share some more code?

Comment: Changed PRoject__c to Project__c but still the same

Comment: Can you share HTML code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it is actually a timing issue - getRecord is an async operation, so you need the template to check for it before it renders - this works for me

```
<template>
    <template if:true={record}>
    <lightning-map
            map-markers={mapMarkers}>
    </lightning-map>
    </template>
</template>
```

//js controller

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ADDRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c.Address__c';

export default class StackExample extends LightningElement {
@track mapMarkers;
@track zoomLevel;
@track record;

    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ADDRESS_FIELD] })
    wiredProject({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.record));
            this.mapMarkers = [
               {
                   location: {
                       Street: this.record.fields.Address__c.value,
                       City: 'Washington',
                       State: 'DC',
                   },
               },
           ];
           this.zoomLevel = 5;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `this.project.ADDRESS_FIELD.value` is incorrect,
the correct way would be

```
this.project.data.fields.fieldAPiname.value
```

ADDRESS_FIELD returns result like -> `{fieldApiName: "FieldApi", objectApiName: "ObjApi"}`

So you cannot use it in '.' reference.

Another way is

```
this.project.data.fields[ADDRESS_FIELD.fieldApiName].value
```

**Or**

You need to use getFieldValue.

Update your import statement as below

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

Use below code to get field value

```
getFieldValue(this.record, field)
```

- [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value)
- [Example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/c0ddd487838466ab64ee9ac0af4287fd1bed6552/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetRecordStaticContact/wireGetRecordStaticContact.js)

Comment: Technically you are right but you can actually access the value of field by `this.project.data.fields.Address__c.value` but Json's issue is that `this.project` is undefined for some reason. Using `getFieldValue` method will result in similar error.

Comment: @BartoszŚliwiński the line `this.project.ADDRESS_FIELD.value` is incorrect

Comment: @BartoszŚliwiński I have updated my answer with a detailed description

Comment: yes, it is incorrect. But the issue doesn't lie in it but in undefined `this.project`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation.
This did not work.
  if:true={contacts}

This worked.
 if:true={contacts.data}